# Join returns only first item in t2 for all rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2016 Express. This query returns data as expected:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) 
    [ResourceID],
    [OrganizationID],
    [CategoryID],
    [SubCategoryID]
FROM 
    [dbo].[Resources]
```

For `OrganizationID` I get  1,2,3,4,5,6 etc.

This query on the other hand:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) 
    [ResourceID],
    [OrganizationID]
FROM 
    [dbo].[Resources]
```

returns all 1s for `OrganizationID` 1,1,1,1 etc

Been doing SQL Server since 1990; never have I seen this before. Please, someone have an explanation.

Comment: Without sample data nobody can really help here. But you have top 1000 in both queries with no order by so you have no way of ensuring which rows are returned. [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: You need `ORDER BY` to sort rows which ensures sorting of rows to use with `TOP`.

Answer (score 3):

`TOP` without defining an **explicit** sort order by using `ORDER BY` is a game of randomness - you get back *some arbitrary* 1000 rows, without really knowing what "top 1000" they are (since SQL Server is free to order in any way it may choose - there is no system inherent default ordering, by primary key or anything else - no `ORDER BY` == no defined ordering) ...

What if you add `ORDER BY ResourceID` or `ORDER BY ResourceID, OrganizationID` to both queries? Do you get back the same results now?

Comment: Yeah, I need to take some anti-Moron pills. Order By was the oh so obvious clue,

Comment: @IbrahimMalluf: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.